# Non-readable POM(The system cannot find the path specified) error with share project over network

Tags: java, maven

Non-readable POM error when i share project over the local network.The POM is working fine on my PC but over the network the other PC is showing the error that Non-readable POM(The system cannot find the path specified). Can any one tell me how to resolve that problem. I shall be thankful :)

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem.Please cut this all text inside pom.xml and  paste again.then Clean project.For me it was solved.Try this..Good luck.